Why didn't Lisa Cuddy appear in the show finale?
The finale episode of House featured cameos appearances of many of the show's prominent actors, including Cameron, Kutner, Amber and Stacy.
Cuddy was one of the show's main characters for multiple seasons.
Another question addresses why she didn't return as a regular character in the final season, but she didn't even make a cameo appearancecin the last episode, Why not?
Was it simply too expensive to hire her actress?

I don't think this is a duplicate. Other actors did not appear in the season but did make an appearance in cameo. That makes this a separate question

@Valorum The duplicate does mention the fact that Cuddy didn't return for the finale whereas many other characters did.

@F1Krazy - I see her not being in the season entire as a very much different question than why she didn't even make a cameo appearance in the finale episode

According to ScreenRant, they wanted to cut down on costs for the show, so when contract negotiations came up they wanted to reduce the actors' pay. Edelstein disagreed and left the show.
By the time of the House finale she was busy on other projects and could not make it.

This was partly down to Lisa Edelstein being busy on other projects, but the actress departed the show under less-than-ideal circumstances.


How much did she want for 1.5 min appearance I wonder..

This article just seems to be a bunch of baseless assertion. The only quote they've offered is from an interview in Hello! where she talks about her personal final episode, but there's nothing concrete about why she didn't return for the finale.

@BoppityBop 1.5 minutes of airtime is the result of several hours or days of set time. Actors aren’t usually paid based on screen time.

Apparently Edelstein felt that returning for the funeral would have been wrong for her character

"I mean come on. It kind of all worked out. Let's tell it like it is. He drove a f**king car through her living room. With the baby and family inside.
"That's crazy. You file a police report and you leave - and you don't come back for the f∗∗king finale."
Lisa Edelstein doesn't regret missing out on the House finale: 'That show wasn't about happy endings'

